# Windows Phone - Image cache - wait for download an image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, caching

I made a project to Cache Images. I want to wait in main thread for complete DownloadImage function and then return that saved bitmap. Is that possible? 
Am I doing it even properly?

```
public static ImageSource GetImage(int id)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        String fileName=string.Format("ImageCache/{0}.jpg", id);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("ImageCache"))
            {
                myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("ImageCache");
            }

            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    bitmap.SetSource(fileStream);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DownloadImage(id);
                //HERE - how to wait for end of DownloadImage and then do that below??
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    bitmap.SetSource(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Here is DownloadImage function:

```
    private static void DownloadImage(Object id)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(string.Format("http://example.com/{0}.jpg", id)), id);
    }
    private static void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
            {
                try
                {
                    string fileName = string.Format("ImageCache/{0}.jpg", e.UserState);
                    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);

                    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.SetSource(e.Result);
                    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);

                    // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
                    Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
                    fileStream.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Exception handle appropriately for your app  
                }
            }  
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many way to achieve what you want. It is possible to wait with `async await` command which is part of Visual Studio Async.
You can download the latest CTP from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9983). [More how to use it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Personally I would use events.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
When I try to use async await I get error of convertion Task<ImageSource> to ImageSource. 
Can you give me an example how to do that properly? or better if you would write something how to do it using events?

Comment: Just move 
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    bitmap.SetSource(fileStream);
                }
to the end of client_OpenReadCompleted and you are fine.

Comment: But then I won't be able to return the bitmap as a return of `public static ImageSource GetImage(int id)`

Answer (score 0):

This one contains some details and code example: http://www.ben.geek.nz/2010/07/one-time-cached-images-in-windows-phone-7/